# Fetch list data from database in Joomla component

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am creating custom component in joomla and it saves list data in database like these:
["2013-05-04","2013-05-05","2013-05-06","2013-05-07","2013-05-08","2013-05-09","2013-05-10","2013-05-11","2013-05-12"]

Is there any way so that i can fetch these data nicely on module ?

Thanks.

Comment: is it a single record?

Comment: Hi toretto, I have done it through json_decode()

Comment: So you got an array after decode it? isn't it.

Comment: yes i got it after using this function

Comment: So what you want?Please provide the actual output what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i got your question you want to show these out put in you module.See the below example:

```
<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

$output = json_decode($json , true);

print_r($output);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [b] => 2
    [c] => 3
    [d] => 4
    [e] => 5
)
```

Then you can use this output as below:

```
<?php 
   foreach ($output as $value){
       echo $value;
   }
?>
```

For more info check the this : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

It is done through json_decode() function.